# Android: Recorded video is black after applying OpenGL effect on Moto G2

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, shader, grafika

I'm applying a visual effect on a video using OpenGL. The effect is separately applied to the video preview and the part where it is saved to the file, the same way as it works in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), [CameraCaptureActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java).

This works perfectly fine on a Nexus 5.
Whereas on a Moto G2 the preview works fine, but the saved video has only black frames.
The OpenGL effect applying part for each frame happens in a **common class for both the preview and the saving** *(although they are separate objects)*.

I have verified the data being sent to the OpenGL program they seem to have valid data.

Has anybody come across such an issue?